# Regex to match "AAAA:AAA" pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

A string must begin with 3 or 4 letters (not numbers), and a ":" symbol should follow these letters, and after the colon there should be three more characters, like `AAA`. For example, `AAAA:AAA` or `AAA:AAA`.

I`m starting to build this, but regex is so much pain for me, can anyone help me with this?

Here is what I have now:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,4}(:)$
```

Comment: Look this: _https://regex101.com/r/uD7qO3/1_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is almost there: you need to add `[a-zA-Z]{3}`.
I prefer the [`[[:alpha:]]` POSIX class in Ruby](http://rubular.com/r/WFaecqaWhp) to match letters though.

> `/[[:alpha:]]/` - *Alphabetic character*
>   
>  POSIX bracket expressions are also similar to character classes. They provide a portable alternative to the above, **with the added benefit that they encompass non-ASCII characters.**

So, here is a possible regex:

```
\A[[:alpha:]]{3,4}:[[:alpha:]]{3}\z
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/WFaecqaWhp)

The regex matches:

- `\A` - start of string (in RoR, you have to use `\A` instead of `^`, or you will get errors)
- `[[:alpha:]]{3,4}` - 3 or 4 letters
- `:` - literal `:`
- `[[:alpha:]]{3}` - 3 letters
- `\z` - end of string (in RoR, you have to use `\z` instead of `$`, or you will get errors)

To allow just `AAA` or `AAAA`, you need to introduce an optional (`?` quantifier) non-capturing group (`(?:...)` construction):

```
\A[[:alpha:]]{3,4}(?::[[:alpha:]]{3})?\z
                  ^^^               ^^
```

See [another demo](http://rubular.com/r/5mofypL0TM)

Comment: Thats work, but in ruby on rails, i have an error - ArgumentError: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?
Can u fix this?

Comment: Use `\A` and `\z`. It is a very well-known issue that is why I added that in my regex description. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, and for the end, it possible to make it valid?
AAA, and AAAA, without colon, or if colon presence, next letters must be 3 or less, but no more.

Comment: I updated the regex: [`\A[[:alpha:]]{3,4}(?::[[:alpha:]]{3})?\z`](http://rubular.com/r/5mofypL0TM).

Answer (score 3):

Try using this (quotes if regex in your dialect must be passed as a string)

```
"^[a-zA-Z]{3,4}:[a-zA-Z]{3}$"
```